# How to add my additional functionalities into an existing flutter package from pub.dev by extending it?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, inheritance, mobile

I have use vimeoplayer plugin from pub.dev but the problem is that the package is not upto my standard so I need to add additional functionalities into it and do some modifications. The problem is I dont want to modify or add inside its dart files and instead I want to extend the widget and add those required changes.

So is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: if the package has less code then copy that code and do changes according to your requirements

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want in several ways. Let me explain them.

**#1 (Fastest one for you)**

You can fork the project from GitHub to your own repository. Make the changes on your version and use that version. You can check the example below on how to use it.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  vimeoplayer:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/BestOfBest/vimeoplayer.git
      ref: main # optional branch name
```

**#2**

You can create an issue and discuss the details and offer to help the person to implement these stuff. This way you can be a OSS contributer and actually have what you need on the actual library.

**#3 (Similar to #1 but not recommended by me)**

You can download the project from GitHub to your own computer. Make the changes on your computer and add the library to your project as a whole. You can check the example below on how to use it.

```
dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter
   vimeoplayer:
     path: ./vimeoplayer
```

**#4**

If it is super simple additional features you can use extension functions.

Extension functions are there to help you out on adding additional functionality to existing libraries. You may check out the usages and what they are on [official documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)

```
// The code is just an example. 
extension VimeoPlayerExtensions on VimeoPlayer {
  int moveTenSecondsForward() {
    return this.forward(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Can you please elaborate on the last topic the extension one